# insanity is free()

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, free, structure

In my simple C program (gnu linux) I am getting the rss value from proc/stat.
`int GetRSS()` returns the RSS value from proc/stat for my process.

---

In this instance:

```
printf("A RSS=%i\n", GetRSS());
char *cStr = null;
cStr = malloc(999999);
if (cStr != NULL)
{
    printf("B RSS=%i\n", GetRSS());
    free(cStr);
    printf("C RSS=%i\n", GetRSS());
}
```

I get:

```
A RSS=980
B RSS=984
C RSS=980
```

I can't explain why `C` did not return `984`.

---

If I run the same procedure twice I get:

```
A RSS=980
B RSS=984
C RSS=980
B RSS=984
C RSS=980
```

Looks fine.

---

But, in this instance:

```
struct _test
{
    char *pChar;
}
struct _test **test_ptr;

int i = 0;
printf("D RSS=%i\n",GetRSS());
assert(test_ptr = (struct _test **)malloc( (10000) * sizeof(struct _test *)));

for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    assert(test_ptr[i] = (struct _test *)malloc(sizeof(struct _test)));
    test_ptr[i]->pChar=strdup("Some garbage");
}

printf("E RSS=%i\n", GetRSS());

for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    free(test_ptr[i]->pChar);
    free(test_ptr[i]);
}

free(test_ptr);
printf("F RSS=%i\n", GetRSS());
```

I get:

```
D RSS=980
E RSS=1024
F RSS=1024
D RSS=1024
E RSS=1024
F RSS=1024
```

Huh? Why is the memory not freeing here?

Comment: You should never put expressions with side effect into `assert`.

Comment: True enough.  Ignore it.  Still, the result is baffling.

Comment: Run your program under "strace" so you can monitor the mmap / munmap calls that would actually have an effect on the RSS value. You can put some printfs around the code so you can match the mmap / munmap to specific points of your code in the output.

Comment: Are the results consistent if you run your program multiple times? Seems like the system needn't swap out a page immediately after freeing memory allocated on that page.

Comment: @vanza: a great suggestion.  I see mmap2 and munmap with the conventional malloc for char *cTemp=malloc(100); free(cTemp);... for the structure malloc, although RSS increases, strace does not show any mmap or munmap calls!!

Answer (score 5):

The fact that a block of memory has been freed does *not* necessarily make that block the most eligible for a subsequent allocation. There are several strategies for a memory manager to select a block of memory (best fit, worst fit, first fit).

Most memory managers also attempt to coalesce free blocks, but some try to let the free blocks "age" as long as possible before coalescing, on the theory that as they age, there's a better chance that blocks next to them will also be freed, improving the success rate at coalescing blocks (thus reducing fragmentation).

The fact that the block wasn't used to satisfy your next allocation request does *not* mean it wasn't freed.

Answer (score 2):

From the `free()` man page: "Occasionally, free can actually return memory to the operating system and make the process smaller. Usually, all it can do is allow a later call to malloc to reuse the space. In the meantime, the space remains in your program as part of a free-list used internally by malloc."

Comment: In the case of the real program that spawned this question, it eventually runs out of memory and crashes.  My testing reveals that memory allocated to the structure doesn't get released.  Further, strace does not show mmap2 or munmap calls associated with the malloc and free of the structure (and its char*).  I'm still stumped.

Comment: @MarkRichards: I just stepped through your program in WinDbg (don't have a linux machine handy to play with now), checking on the committed memory with `!heap`. It works fine. Doesn't seem to be any memory leaks. Remeber that glibc's `malloc` and `free` needn't call mmap/munmap, as there is already uncomitted memory reserved for the CRTs heap. What do you mean eventually runs out of memory and crashes? Can you maybe pastebin you entire program?

Comment: Very interesting.  I will do the same on another (different) box.  I modified the program - removed the first, working malloc.  Still fails to call mmap.  see: http://pastebin.com/m3gAJBhs

Comment: Testing the same code on another box (ubuntu) I see some, not all, of the allocated memory in the structure freed - based on reading RSS.  On the target box, an arm9 processor running debian, I see none of the memory freed, again based against reading RSS.  Same code.  Different boxes.  Different results.  I wouldn't be so persistent about this if my program didn't crash after running for a few hours from lack of resources.  Only happens with the dynamic structures, so I am wondering.. am I coding these correctly??

Comment: RSS won't tell you if the memory has been freed or not, because the CRT can hold on to that memory for future allocations as others have said. Try calling glibc's undocumented `malloc_stats()` (from GDB or just stick it in between your calls to malloc or free) or using valgrind. The code you posted is correct in that you free everything you malloc. Theoretically, certain allocation patterns can cause specific malloc implementations to commit more and more memory to the heap, due to fragmentation. If this is the case there are ways to deal with that, but the code you posted shouldn't have that

Comment: problem. Can you post a whole program that exhibits the problem? I'd be interested to take a look. You say it crashes after a few hours but the program you pastebinned halts immediately.

Comment: what I posted is a simple static test.  I will send you a link to a tar.gz for you to ponder.  The entire system requires a bunch of libraries and some of these are custom.  Also in order to get the whole dynamic, you'll need some hardware, and I'll help you get around that.  Although this may prove academic..

It just so happens that I found two rather awful memory leaks during this process.. and since then memory use is stable (appears dynamic and as you and others suggest is being done on the system).

So problem may be solved.. we shall see as it runs overnight.

Comment: @nm:send email address  please.  Cant find method thru stack overflow to contact you.  Thanks.

Comment: @MarkRichards, enndubyu -AT- gmail -DOT- com

Answer (score 1):

Your malloc library elected not to do that. It may be for strategic reasons (to avoid having to go to the system for more memory later) or it may be due to limitations (in that particular cause, it doesn't recognize that it can free the memory).

In general, it doesn't matter. Address space and virtual memory are typically not considered scarce resources. So excessive effort to minimize their consumption is generally worthless at best and often harmful.